# How do I troubleshoot a Python script that should log into a Windows server when there are no error messages?

Tags: python, linux, windows, powershell, winrm

My Ansible playbooks are not working for my Windows servers (2012).  They've never worked correctly.  I installed pywinrm (0.1.1) on a CentOS 7 server.  I have Python 2.7.5.  I have a basic Python script that imports winrm.  I have hardcoded the credentials of a local account (not a domain account) to the Windows server.  The script should connect to a Windows server, but there are no error messages, and it appears to fail.

```
import winrm
session = winrm.Session('nameOfWindowsServer', auth=('localUser', 'password'))
```

I ran a PowerShell script that prepares the server to be used by winrm.  I see no activity in the Windows Server event log.  How do I get this Python script to log into the Windows Server?  It seems to be silently failing.  I expect some activity in the Event Viewer of the Windows server.

Update: As the failure was silent, I added to my two line script.  I added this third line of Python code:

```
remotecom = session.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])
```

I got this as an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last) ... File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-ackages/winrm/**init**.py", line 29, in
>   run_cmd ... File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-ackages/winrm/**init**.py",
>   line 121, in run_cmd ... File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-ackages/winrm/**init**.py", line 193, in
>   run_cmd ... File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-ackages/winrm/**init**.py",
>   line 125, in run_cmd ... winrm.exceptions.UnauthorizedError: 401
>   Unauthorized

Why I am getting this error?  Why am I not seeing activity on the Windows server?  Should the local user have something to denote it is not a domain login?

Comment: Have you checked the `Security` event log on the windows machine for logon events for `localUser`?

Comment: Yes.  There was no activity there.